# [].splice.apply or [].splice.push etc

Tags: javascript

over the last couple days I have been studying some array methods and have seen stuff like `[].splice.apply` and `[].push.apply` with some parameters.

Now I think i understand splice for example

```
var tuna = ['bob', 'john' , 'papa' , 'greg'];
var newArr = []
tuna.splice(0,2,"hello");
console.log(tuna);
```

will output `hello,papa,greg`, since it deletes 2 terms in the 0th indice.

I also know how apply works in the following context

```
var person = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    getFullName: function() {

        var fullname = this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
        return fullname;

    }
}

var logName = function(lang1, lang2) {

    console.log('Logged: ' + this.getFullName());
    console.log('Arguments: ' + lang1 + ' ' + lang2);
    console.log('-----------');

}
var logPersonName = logName.bind(person);
logPersonName('en');
logName.call(person, 'en', 'es');
logName.apply(person, ['en', 'es']);
```

So what happens when we combine these two methods, or push with apply ? A simple example would really help.

Comment: `[].splice.push` does not make sense. `[].splice.apply` does, because "apply" is the name of a function on the Function prototype. Now, `[].push.apply` makes sense, for a similar reason.

Comment: Yes, sorry for some reason I typed that without thinking. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

What you've likely seen is:

```
var foo = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
```

This takes the `slice` method of `Array`, i.e. the canonical implementation of `slice`, and uses it on an *array-like* object, and returns an array. This is a shorthand to turn an *array-like* object into an actual array. It is purely used because it is the shortest and most convenient way to achieve this goal. `slice` happens to work on any array-like object and return an actual array, and when not using any of its additional parameters it doesn't do anything else with the array; that's why it's convenient to use for this purpose. It's really *abusing* the slice method for a purpose it wasn't designed for, but since it works everywhere... well, here we are using it.

Example:

```
var o = {};
o[0] = 'foo';
o[1] = 'bar';
o.length = 2;
```

This is an *array-like* object, but it doesn't have any actual array methods. I can't do `o.push('baz')`, because `o` is not an actual array. To turn it into an actual array, I'd use the above method, and can then treat it like an actual array.

Comment: Thanks,do you have any examples of using .splice.apply?

Comment: That's not a typical use I'm aware of, but I'm sure there are situations where it's handy. Come up with your own made-up scenarios.

Comment: By the way is the way you are explaining "apply" here, different from the example I made? I've only learned to use it in that context

Comment: It's not fundamentally different, no. The key part to understand is that functions and objects are very loosely bound together. Even if a function is defined on an object (usually called a "method"), you can take that function and apply it to anything else you want, it doesn't have to be that original object. That is all simply decided at *call time*, not definition time. `apply` is one way to do this, to use an existing function, regardless of where it comes from, and, well, *apply* it to something else.